# How to obtain an n-sided polygon's plane equation from the co-ordinates of the n vertices?

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

We are given `n co-ordinates` like so: `(x1, y1), (x2, y2),.....,(xn, yn)`. The points will form a polygon when connected. The shape of the polygon could be anything (`symmetric or non-symmetric`). If we consider the polygon to be a `2D plane`, in this case, how can we obtain the plane equation of the polygon formed from only the given co-ordinates?
The `z-coordinate` value will always remain `zero`.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Take any three points and determine the plane, because three points are enough to uniquely determine the plane. But before that you must ensure that the figure is planar, not skew.

Comment: If the z-coordinate is always zero, then the plane the polygon's points lie in has the equation z=0.